# Pdf to HTML conversion on server?

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

Is it some how possible to read a PDF file on server and send a user an HTML like result using only PHP?

I m new to web development. Just need a quick and short guide line on 'how to', if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try DocRaptor , send them the PDF and they'll give you the HTML, they are reliable and I often use their service.

http://docraptor.com/try_it_out

Or if you want to do it yourself, this open source software should run on your server

http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/

(or anything else you find suitable)

Comment: It does the opposite : HTML to PDF